# How can i get duplicate elements identified by 2 keys in mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a few million documents for which i need to find at least duplicate document. The duplication criteria is based on 2 keys, not one. So i need to find at least 2 documents which both have `{ property1 : value1, property2 : value2,}`.

For this i am trying to use the aggregate framewotk as in the following example:

```
db.listings.aggregate({
$group: 
{
    _id :  {  property1 : "$property1",     property2 : "$property2" },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
},},{
$match : {
count: { 
    $gt : 1 
}
}},{
$limit: 1})
```

I think this should be working, BUT
Mongo returns the following error:

```
{
    "code" : 16390,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "exception: sharded pipeline failed on shard shard1: { errmsg: \"exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)\", code: 16389, ok: 0.0}"
```

I have also tried

```
db.collection.aggregate( { $group: { _id:
                                { $concat: [ "$property1",
                                             ": ",
                                             "$property2"
                                           ]
                                },
                           count: { $sum: 1 }
                         }
               }
             )
```

Got the same result

Does anyone have a better idea how to do this? I am not really a mongo expert, but i have to do this one way or the other.

Thanks in advance

Comment: After the first _$group_, all result must be grouped in some _mongos_ instance, so your _$limit_ command isn't helping much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to shrink the doc as much as possible with `$concat` is a good one, but `$concat` is a `$project` operator, not a `$group` operator.  So try something like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    { $project: { _id: { $concat: ["$property1", ":", "$property2"] }}},
    { $group: { _id: '$_id', c: { $sum: 1 }}},
    { $match: { c: { $gt: 1 }}})
```

It still may use too much memory, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. So far JhonnyHK's answer really helped me and it didn't return the max size error again. It is well appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using map-reduce is an alternative. Here you can find examples :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/